# How to hand over chat history to human agent ? in Facebook Messenger API from node js

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I have created a bot with IBM watson ,Node js and Facebook Messenger API
and wanted to handover the bot chat history to the human agent with messenger API.

little will be appreciated

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple options.

1. You can do this through the page inbox using the handover protocol:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/handover-protocol#page_inbox

2. You can create a separate app that integrates with whatever support/ticketing/live chat system you have, set it as secondary receiver role, and subscribe it to the standby webhook event to log all activity.